# Broadcast a dictionary to rdd in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am just getting the hang of Spark, and I have function that needs to be mapped to an `rdd`, but uses a global dictionary:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext('local[*]', 'pyspark')

my_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4} # at no point will be modified
my_list = ["a", "d", "c", "b"]

def my_func(letter):
    return my_dict[letter]

my_list_rdd = sc.parallelize(my_list)

result = my_list_rdd.map(lambda x: my_func(x)).collect()

print result
```

The above gives the expected result; however, I am really not sure about my use of the global variable `my_dict`. It seems that a copy of the dictionary is made with every partition. And it just does not feel right..

It looked like [broadcast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) is what I am looking for. However, when I try to use it:

```
my_dict_bc = sc.broadcast(my_dict)

def my_func(letter):
    return my_dict_bc[letter]
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Broadcast' object has no attribute '__getitem__
```

This seems to imply that I cannot broadcast a dictionary.

My question: If I have a function that uses a global dictionary, that needs to be mapped to `rdd`, what is the proper way to do it?

My example is very simple, but in reality `my_dict` and `my_list` are much larger, and `my_func` is more complicated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You forgot something important about `Broadcast` objects, they have a property called [value](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=broadcast#pyspark.Broadcast.value) where the data is stored.

Therefore you need to modify `my_func` to something like this:

```py
my_dict_bc = sc.broadcast(my_dict)

def my_func(letter):
    return my_dict_bc.value[letter]
```

Comment: I see!, So when I add `my_dict_bc.value` it works correctly. And `broadcasting` is a standard approach to work with objects that are being shared, right?

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice, however if the dictionary isn't too large, then you could use a global object without any problem

Comment: Makes sense. Thank You.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto, may I ask you, how to work with a large dictionary?

Comment: @DenisKuzin How large? If it's huge convert it to a DataFrame and use join.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto, dictionary size is about 30Gb. Ok, thanks, good idea

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it depends on how the read-only shared variables (the dictionary in your case) will be accessed in the rest of the program.  In the case you described, you don't need to use a broadcast variable.  From [the Spark programming guide section on broadcast variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables):

> Spark automatically broadcasts the common data needed by tasks within each stage. The data broadcasted this way is cached in serialized form and deserialized before running each task. This means that explicitly creating broadcast variables is only useful when tasks across multiple stages need the same data or when caching the data in deserialized form is important.

In your case, if the data is only needed in the single map stage, there is no need to explicitly broadcast the variable (it is not "useful").  However, if the same dictionary were to be used later in another stage, then you might wish to use broadcast to avoid serializing and deserializing the dictionary before each stage.